# multiple has_many through with same associated model - activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model called game. It has two associations: with :categorytoptens and :categorygames:

```
has_many :categorytoptens
has_many :categories, :through => :categorytoptens, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :categorygames
has_many :categories, :through => :categorygames, :dependent => :destroy
```

To Edit the categories, i added this to my activeadmin games.rb file:

```
    f.input :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Category.all, :member_label => :navititle_de
```

It displays a list of checkboxes of all categories from the categories model and saves the selection in categorygames. So, everything works fine.

BUT: When i change the order of :categorytoptens and :categorygames in the game model, the categories are saved in the categorytoptens:

```
has_many :categorygames
has_many :categories, :through => :categorygames, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :categorytoptens
has_many :categories, :through => :categorytoptens, :dependent => :destroy
```

My questions:

a.) is it "allowed" to have multiple has_many with the same model association? Do the model associations "overwrite" each other?
b.) is there a way to specify the model to be edited in activeadmin?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should not define two has_many association with same name!! never try renaming your associations

```
has_many :categorygames
has_many :games_categories, :through => :categorygames, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :categorytoptens
has_many :top_ten_categories, :through => :categorytoptens, :dependent => :destroy
```

A) You can define two association with same name but successor with override previous one. Try some nice name(uniq) for each association

B) Need more information, do you want to manage a resource in active admin ?

try

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourResourceName do
end
```

you can set custom name for your resource too, follow this link http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename_the_resource

Comment: Many thanks, works like a charm. I had to add ":source => " in the end.